# (Rails) Using "link_to_remote" in conjunction with a popup/popout window...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, popup, link-to, link-to-remote

What is the most straightforward mechanism by which to "link_to_remote" and popout a window with the data?  I need "link_to_remote" because I need to pass certain data along with the url without redoing my routes.  If this would be better served by a "link_to" without the need to redo my routes, I'm all for it.  I simply can't get it to work, atm.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like:

```
<%= link_to_function "Show Article in Popout window",
      "window.open(#{article_path(article).to_json}, 'show_article')" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`link_to_remote`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M001930) is used to do `XHR` requests, so you cannot use it to open a popup window with the response.

You don't need to redo your route anyway, because I assume that if you want to use `link_to*` to get some data, then you have your controller/action pair defined and accessible already.

Also, usually, Rails applications have the `catch all` route enabled to match `:controller/:action`. If that's your case, then you can use `link_to` that controller/action to get the data.

Comment: Well, all the calculations occur in a non-standard/non-restful action "view_chart" based on an item's data.  In any case, how would you recommend I go about it?  link_to "popup" doesn't seem to be working atm.  I'll give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

What window do u mean ? modal window ? if u want to show some data through modal window, then i suggest u to use http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/index.html, it easier to use, just write some js function and create `link_to_function` in rails helper/view to call the js function.